# Retrieving albums from age-restricted (alcohol) pages results in "An unknown error occurred"

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've noticed when doing a Facebook Graph API call to retrieve a list of photo albums on an age-restricted page the following error occurs:

```
{error_code: 1, error_msg: "An unknown error occurred"}
```

I've tried both the JS API and the PHP API, same results.

For testing purposes, I am using an age-restricted page I created myself (permission set to Alcohol-related). I also have double checked that I am using a valid auth_token that has full permission to read and write photos to the page.

```
$albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'GET', array(
  'access_token' => 'XXX'
));
```

Please note the same code works fine on non-age restricted pages.

I should also mention, if I grab an album_id manually from Facebook, I have no problems posting photos to that album. The problem only seems to be with listing the albums.

Is this a bug on Facebook's side, or is there an extra step one must take for age-restriced pages?

Comment: please clarify: me/albums means your albums, not page's albums. what do you mean where it works?

Answer (score 2):

Since the page is age restricted the user viewing this album should pass the age restriction check. Verify that the user viewing this passes that restriction.